# SSRS - report is aborted after 5 minutes, procedure runs 6 minutes in db

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

someone can advise me? I have procedure which runs 6 minutes in database. But when i start report with this procedure so report is aborted after 5 minutes. We have set timeout in Reporting Services on 30 minutes. Report has 550 rows and 32 columns (low size). Before in procedure was INSERT INTO dbo.table now i change it on #table. Can't Report Server remember last problem with insert into dbo.table?

Comment: I am really not sure what your question is. A problem with the timeout, or is there an error on the table? Please update and clarify a) what code you are executing b) the change you're trying to make to the code.

Comment: I think that procedure is OK. In db is procedure successful. But report in browser shows: Loading... but after 5 minutes Report Server has status for this report: rsProcessingAborted.

Comment: I would rephrase your question. 5 minutes is a decent amount of time for a Stored Proc to run for an SSRS report. I can't imagine a user having to wait for 5 minutes for a dataset to return under *most* circumstances. Perhaps as a start you'd like help determine why your code is slow? If so, post the code, and the actual execution plan. [Here is a good guide](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/) on how to do that.

Comment: Can you check the log file for a corresponding thread aborted exception? Also, what is the ssrs client, report manager, report viewer or ssrs api in web app?

Answer (score 0):

check the remote query timeout on SQL Server by running

```
sp_configure 'remote query timeout (s)'
```

If this says 300 then this is likely to be the issue. You can increase this value, check the documentation here..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-query-timeout-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple timeout settings that affect SSRS report execution:

1) On a dataset level:

[image: Timeout on a dataset level]

2) On SSRS instance level, config file `rsreportserver.config`:

```
<Add Key="DatabaseQueryTimeout" Value="120"/>
```

3) In a `web.config` file, which can be found in the same folder as `rsreportserver.config`:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="9000" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

4) In a SSRS configuration table:

```
USE ReportServer
select Name, Value from ConfigurationInfo
WHERE Name in ('SessionTimeout','SystemReportTimeout')
```

If any value changed in 2, 3, 4 the restart of SSRS service is required